# Create SPListItem from ZipArchiveEntry without FileStream

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm a new .Net developper and i'm facing an issue while developping an Uploaded Zip File in a document Library.

i need to extract the content of the Zip File uploaded to do some actions on the files contained in it.

So i choosed to use ZipArchive Stream to handle my problem, i can retrieve my SPFile from my DocLib easily and create the stream from it.

But i'm not able to create embedded files from ZipArchiveEntry, i tried the following piece of code ( not a copy/past, i'm not on my dev machine )

```
foreach(SPFile myFile in mySPFolder.Files)
{
    ZipArchive myZip = new ZipArchive(myFile.OpenBinaryStream());

    foreach(ZipArchiveEntry subZip in ZipArchive.Entries)
    {
        SPFile newFile = list.RootFolder.Add("myxml.xml",subZip.Open())
    }
}
```

I'm facing an issue while creating my newFile as it's throwing me a System I/O error, as per my understanding it's maybe due to the fact that the stream returned by the method ZipArchiveEntry.Open() is a deflatestream.

I saw that the file creation can be done with a MemoryStream, but i'm not able to understand how to convert a deflatestream to a memorystream.

Comment: Could you please try to explain a little better? I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I mean : How to get a MemoryStream from a ZipArchiveEntry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from another place but..

In order to get a memorystream  from a deflatestream you need to use the CopyTo() method from Stream.

```
public void ExtractLibraryZipFolder(SPWeb web, SPList myList, string FolderPath, SPFile myFile, bool overWrite)
    {
        ZipArchive myZip = new ZipArchive(myFile.OpenBinaryStream());

        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry subZip in myZip.Entries)
        {
            MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            subZip.Open().CopyTo(myMemoryStream);
            if (FolderPath != string.Empty)
            {
                SPFolder theFolder = web.GetFolder("/ImportToolLibrary/");
                theFolder.SubFolders[FolderPath].Files.Add(subZip.Name, myMemoryStream);
            }
            else
            {
                SPFile myUpload = myList.RootFolder.Files.Add(subZip.Name, myMemoryStream);
            }                
        }
    }
```